# Excel input to java date

Tags: java, date, datetime, epoch

I have an excel sheet with a cell containing a date value of 4 September 1920 which I want to parse and use into my application. Extracting it from the excel sheet works fine but it doesn't convert the date properly. The interesting thing is that when I extract the cell that contains the `datevalue` from the excel sheet it doesn't return a `dateformat` or anything, instead it returns a double value.

I need to convert this double value (7552.0) into a valid `Date` object but I can't seem to do this properly, this is the closest that I have gotten so far:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("D").parse(getDateFromExcelAsString())
```

the `getDateFromExcelAsString()` method converts the double to a string:

```
String.valueOf(dateAsDouble.intValue())
```

The problem is that this method converts the 7552.0 double value to date: 4 September 1990. But this should be 3 September 1920.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using different references.
For excel day 0 is 31/Dec/1899 and for the Date class day 0 is 1/Jan/1970 and that causes that 70 year deviation.

I've tested a simple and ugly solution like:

```
double value = 7552;
Date date = new Date(0);
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTime(date);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, (int) value - 25569);
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM yyyy").format(cal.getTime()));
```

And the console output is the expected:

```
3 September 1920
```

EDIT:
Since in your question you are using SimpleDateFormat to parse the excel value, I'll add here the quick and not clean solution using that approach (instead of Calendar).

```
double value = 7552;
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("D");
Date date = inputFormat.parse("" + (value - 25568));
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMMM yyyy");
System.out.println(outputFormat.format(date));
```

Once again console outputs is:

```
3 September 1920
```

Note that now the day offset is 25568 as day 0 for SimpleDateFormat is 31/Dec/1969.

Comment: So if I understand your solution correctly, your suggestion is to substract 70 years from the date in java (in amount of day day's i.e. 25569) to compensate the difference in format with the excel way of interpreting a date (in day's)?

Comment: That sounds like a quick work-around, not very clean - like you mentioned - but its a quick solution for now, so thank you for the answer, I'll still wait for a better and less 'hacky' answer but +1 because this work around works temporarily.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed a hacky workaround. I've been thinking about it but I couldn't see any strategy other than subtracting the offset. I've added also a solution using SimpleDateFormat as you were doing in the question.